# Accordion item disappearing after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, css

I implemented an accordion on this page: https://www.oct.ca/public/media/announcements/covid-19-news-and-resources

After about 3 seconds of clicking on the accordion item the title disappears.

It looks like something is adding "opacity: 0" to the button element.

Comment: The blue one on the bottom ? Works fine for me. Help me to fine the issue please ;)